# loop to readline() breaks without exceptions

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently trying to create an App which enables me to control an Arduino board. For some reason, whenever it gets to the stage where the server waits for a message and gets to this loop, the loop breaks without any exceptions thrown when there is no action taken.
What I mean is that if I don't use any buttons to control the board, the loop breaks.

```
for(;;) {
    if(message.equals("END")) {
        break;
    }
    message = "";

    switch (arduinoState) {
        case 1: sendMessage("Server[Cmd]: fwd");
                arduinoState = 0;
                break;
        case 2: sendMessage("Server[Cmd]: right");
                arduinoState = 0;
                break;
        case 3: sendMessage("Server[Cmd]: bwd");
                arduinoState = 0;
                break;
        case 4: sendMessage("Server[Cmd]: left");
                arduinoState = 0;
                break;
        case 5: sendMessage("Server[Cmd]: kante");
                arduinoState = 0;
                break;
    }
    message = input.readLine();
    updateStatusHandler.post(new updateStatusThread("Arduino: " + message, false));
}
```

**EDIT:** As requested once, [here is the Server class](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlzW0pDKtJ_rjXGysF7kJU6W5kud).

Comment: Add a default case to your switch it looks like it doesn't hit any case cause you set the variable to 0. what does `sendMessage(xx);` do ? can you share the entire method or class cause the problem might be outside of what you have shown.

Comment: It hadn't had a big impact when the default case was in there. `sendMessage(String s)` sends a message to the client which is the Arduino board.

Could it be that doing everything in one .java file is the cause? I had some issues regarding accessing TextViews through other classes as it always said that I was using the TextViews in non-static contexts. And as I was googling around, it appeared that you could get all classes in one file which then solved the accessing issue.

[Click here for the Server class.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlzW0pDKtJ_rjXGysF7kJU6W5kud)

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention is the fact that the loop breaks exactly at `input.readline()` when there are no messages sent by client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution. The problem was that `message = input.readLine();` keeps reading lines till the stream ends. As `arduinoState = 0`, no message will be sent to the client as there's no action to do thus no message from the client will be returned. This ends to a continously loop of reading. This means that even if I would change `arduinoState`, nothing will happen.

**Solution:** What I did was creating a class which is treated like a thread. Message will now on be sent independently from the `waitForConnection()` method. 
`sendMessageThread` are used in `setOnClickListeners()` for buttons I use in the app.

```
class sendMessageThread implements Runnable {
    private String s = "";
    public sendMessageThread(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mWriter.write(s + '\n');
            mWriter.flush();
            mHandler.post(new updateStatusThread("Befehl gesendet: \"" + s + "\"", false));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I had to do a workaround lowering StrictMode. Why? Although I'm using a thread to take network actions, the exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown. I guess it's because I'm using `mWriter (BufferedWriter)` as a global reference. I fetch the `BufferedWriter` in `whileConnected()` in the `Server` class.

**StrictMode workaround:**

```
 //Remember to set it in the onCreate() method, 
 //right after super.onCreate() and setContentView()
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

**`whileConnected()` method**

```
private void whileConnected() {
    try {
        mWriter = this.output;
        do {
            input.ready();

            String line;
            while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.length() > 0) {
                    mHandler.post(new updateStatusThread("Arduino: " + line, false));
                    break;
                }
            }

        } while (!message.equals("END"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

If you still have any questions or tips and tricks to improve myself, feel free to leave an answer or comment down below.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the issue is infinite looping on UI thread, it's just a guess.

Also, have you tried while loop?

Comment: It doesn't make of a big difference. I previously used `while(true)` before and the results are the same.